# Yii : What can block access to $_POST data?

Tags: post, yii, controls

I am sending a post to a controller / action (not ajax).

Inside the action, I am doing the standard way of checking to see if it was a post (the exact way works in other actions I am using).

```
if( isset( $_POST['LessonForm'] ) )
{
 ...
}
else
{
   Yii::trace( "Post Not Set" );        
}
```

And the post is always not set.

However, if I put a `var_dump( $_POST ); die();` in front of the conditional, I get this:

```
array(2) { ["LessonForm"]=> array(3) { ["title"]=> string(4) "test" ["shortDescription"]=> string(4) "test" ["image"]=> string(0) "" } ["yt1"]=> string(0) "" }
```

So the post is clearly there. Furthermore,

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value )
{
    echo( $key.'<br>' );
}
```

I get this:

```
LessonForm
yt1
```

Further suggesting the post is there.

When trying to use the variable in $_POST, it is not there. If accessing it in a foreach loop and assigning it to a variable, I can vardump the variable but not use it.

To test if it was a accessControl problem, I removed all filters.

What can block access like this?

**Update:**

@Stu is correct in that it is not being sent as a POST. The form method is post. Not sure how else to force a post?

**Update 2:**

Problem is fixed, but I'm still not sure what was causing the CActiveForm to send a get rather than post and still include post data.

After removing the transaction from the model save, the problem vanished (it should not have been there in the first place).

**Update 3:**

The original problem was an actionCreate. That problem mysteriously vanished. Next was an actionEdit. The view rendered (with the form) is the same file. The action was copied and pasted with modifications as to how the data was being saved and getting the model rather than making a new one.

After looking at the network traffic, there is a post followed immediately by a 302 redirect that isn't in my code. For some reason Yii is forcing a 302 redirect to get to the action.

Comment: Have you tried `if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest){ }`?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but the array(2) shouldn't be array(1) ?. It means it is inside another and thats why is not being set in the first level array.

Comment: @Stu you're on to something there. `if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest){ }` suggests that it isn't a post. However, the form method is post. Digging deeper.

Comment: @jcalonso `array(2)` is just saying it's an array with two nodes, in this case `LessonForm` and `yt1`

Comment: Hmm... can you edit your question adding your whole form and controller action?

Comment: @Stu is true, sorry for that.

Comment: I just fixed it. Not sure how. I took the model save out of a transaction. Which should have nothing to do with it being a post or a get.

Answer (score 0):

Yii has already abstracted out getting request variables whether they're `POST` or `GET`

Use: `Yii::app()->request->getParam('SomeVarName', 'ADefaultValue');`

To get a request variable and returning a sensible default if one doesn't exist. If you're having trouble sending the variables from the form in the first place though, that could be a different issue.